# Does nodejs automatically delete non-global variables?

Tags: node.js, express

Example code in Express:

```
app.post('/photo', async (req, res,next) => {
    // other codes
    let buffer = await readFile(file.path, 'utf8');
    // other codes
}
```

The variable `buffer` has a large value. If the post request finished, will nodejs automatically delete the `buffer`? Or if there are many requests, will there be many `buffer`s that increase memory usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as this request finishes and assuming you don't store the `buffer` data anywhere else, then that data will immediately be eligible for garbage collection.

> If the post request finished, will nodejs automatically delete the buffer?

Yes, at the next cycle of garbage collection.

> Or if there are many requests, will there be many buffers that increase memory usage?

If you have a whole bunch of rapid fire requests that keep node.js very busy, it might take a short while before the garbage collector gets to run and cleans up that data.

---

Data in Javascript becomes eligible for garbage collection when there are no longer any live references to the data in reachable code (code that could actually run and reference that data).  So, in your example, as soon as the request handler finishes, then the `buffer` variable no longer has any live code that can ever reach that variable.  That means its reference count goes to zero and the garbage collector will be able to reclaim the memory that data occupies when it next runs.